# Difference between "besides", "apart from" and "except for". Prepositions vs adverbials

Tags: meaning, prepositions, adverbials, discourse-markers

I am studying discourse markers and ended up checking online (in crownacademyenglish) about the difference between these expressions.

Firstly, this website affirms that they are prepositions, which I disagree with. They can also be adverbials. Secondly, I am not sure I agree with the difference in meaning it suggests. I would like you to confirm my doubts with examples, if possible. Also, to show if, in fact, it is their word type that could produce such a difference in meaning in some contexts.

The text states that *besides* adds something to the clause. It means "plus".
*Except* (of) means minus; it has a meaning of excluding something.
*Apart from* is a combination of the two, meaning plus / minus depending on the context.

So, basically what I'm hearing is that a sentence like

- *Next week, I’ll be in London every day besides Monday*

is incorrect. Is this so?

Perhaps I am wrongly influenced by their equivalent expressions in Spanish, but to me, they mean basically the same.

To add something to the post, this is the definition of **besides** in an online dictionary:

> *As an adverb:*
>
> - Meaning moreover; furthermore; also: "Besides, I promised her we would come."
> - Meaning in addition: "There are three elm trees and two maples besides".
> - Meaning otherwise; else: "They had a roof over their heads but not much besides."
>
> *As a preposition:*
>
> - Meaning over and above; in addition to: "Besides a mother he has a sister to support."
> - Meaning other than; except: "There's no one here besides Bill and me."

Is there something I am not grasping? Thanks.

Comment: You're right; you've spotted one of the many idiosyncrasies English suffers from/is blessed with. In 'There's no one here besides/except Bill and me', the two synonyms are interchangeable, with only a hint of a more formal register with 'except'. But in 'Next week, I’ll be in London every day except Monday', 'besides' sounds unnatural (and I've found no relevant examples in ...

Comment: [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=every+day+besides&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cevery%20day%20besides%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cevery%20day%20besides%3B%2Cc0) for 'every day besides'.) And zero returns for 'every day besides Monday' (x7, + 'weekends'). 'Besides' meaning 'except' has a far more restricted distribution. People are often the prepositional complement ('besides John / him / the kids ...'). // Note that prepositional usage is not the discourse marker meaning 'And another reason to ... ,/ not to ... ,'.

Comment: A discourse marker cannot be a preposition.....besides Monday = except for Monday. Same thing. Not a discourse marker. It would be if you were arguing with someone and provide another reason for something: Besides, I really hate hot dogs. And there, it means also. Adverbs are also usually  not discourse markers.

Comment: My issue is definitely some interferience from Spanish. "Besides (Spanish: Aparte), I really hate hot dogs". Apartar (verb) also means to move away or to separate. So, it is quite similar, but their maps of meaning now I am fluent in both languages are totally mixed in my head. "I’ll be in London every day besides Monday" does actually sound a bit off to me. The problem was that I couldn't tell why nor can I see how to interiorize the difference in meaning. Anyway, in the practice I tend to use "apart" or "except" due to the same Spanish interference. Besides, who needs the word besides.

Comment: You cannot compare prepositions and adverbials. Preposition is a word class (part of speech) and adverbial is a function that can be performed by a range of expressions, not just prepositions.

Comment: "Besides" is a preposition, whether or not it has a complement. In appropriate constructions it is in competition with "apart from" and "except for".